# How to get rows only contains multiple ID using SQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Let say I have this table:

```
id | foo
1  | 100
1  | 200
1  | 200
2  | 300
2  | 300
3  | 200
4  | 100
```

I am expecting to have this result:

```
id | foo
1  | 100
1  | 200
1  | 200
2  | 300
2  | 300
```

I want to get only rows that have multiple `id` log, regardless of the `foo` value.

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina MySQL version 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variant 1 ([The Censored DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/70800/the-censored-dba)'s [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/225830/150107) with syntax correction):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id 
              FROM tablename
              GROUP BY id
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Variant 2 (subquery in FROM clause):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tablename t1
JOIN ( SELECT id 
       FROM tablename
       GROUP BY id
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

The index by `id` is safe for to increase performance in both variants.

---

Variant 3. To improve performance you can try to use temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (id INT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=Memory;

INSERT INTO temp
SELECT id 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

SELECT t1.* 
FROM tablename t1
JOIN temp t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SQL> select * from dummy;

    ID    FOO
---------- ----------
     1    100
     1    200
     1    200
     2    300
     2    300
     3    200
     4    200

7 rows selected.

SQL> select * from dummy where id in (select id from dummy having count(*) > 1 group by id);

    ID    FOO
---------- ----------
     1    100
     1    200
     1    200
     2    300
     2    300

SQL>
```

Comment: Syntax error. GROUP BY must precede HAVING. And on a huge array of data WHERE..IN must be too expensive...

Comment: I was about to use subquery like that as well.. But on second thought, the IDs to be checked is millions, so it must be too expensive..